# Swipe ViewPager Tabs - alinhamento, mudança de cor de icone, voltar a page 0 e encolher a toolbar

Tags: java, android

Olá,
Fiz no código abaixo um ViewPager com Tabs: 
No código da Main:

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
SwipeRefreshLayout refresh;
ParseUser currentUser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

final int[] tabIcons = new int[]{
        R.drawable.mainazul,
        R.drawable.lupaazul,
        R.drawable.menuazul
};

private void setupTabIcons() {

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentoMain());
    adapter.addFragment(new PesquisaFrag());
    adapter.addFragment(new Menu());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }}
```

No meu xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/branca"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

As Tabs são somente com ícones, sem texto.

Está funcionando bem, mas estou com as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Quando o celular está na vertical, os ícones estão bem distribuídos na tela. Quando está na horizontal eles se alinham no centro. Como mudar isto?

2.Os ícones ficam sempre da mesma cor. Tem como alterá-los conforme a page estiver selecionada.

3. Quando estou na page 1 ou 2 e aperto o botão voltar do celular, sai. Gostaria que voltasse para a page 0, ao invés de sair da aplicação.
4. Achei que com "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"" a toolbar (onde está o nome do Aplicativo) encolheria. Mas isto não está acontecendo. Como encolher a toolbar?

Obrigada.

Comment: Você vai precisar reescrever seu codigo:
1- aqui, voce precisa criar um layout para exibir a activity em modo landscape, para isso, crie uma pasta layout-land e copie o layout.xml nessa pasta, basicamente é o mesmo layout.  
2- Aqui, voce precisa criar uma imagem diferente para setar como o icone para a tab selecionada e mudar os icones programaticamente.
3- nessa, voce precisa detectar a back key do device, e instanciar o método `@override ... onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) ...` e ao invés de fechar o app, mudar para outra tab.
4- Precisa explicar melhor o que voce quer.

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho, olá Armando, pode me explicar melhor como voltar para a page 1. Não entendi.

Comment: voce deve ter uma variavel setada com o contador da tab em que está no foco, dai, instancia o método OnKeydown da sua activity e verifica se o usuario apertou "back", se foi isso e a variavel com o nr da tab em foco for > 0 e <= nrTabs, decrementa a variavel e comanda o tabmanager para focar uma de suas tabs com esse novo valor, e se for zero e vc quiser q o programa feche, acompanha o fluxo do metodo e sai do programa ou faz o que vc quizer com a sua tela.